# Auto updating list scrolling

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am basically making a auto updating image scroller. When jQuery sends a ajax request and finds out a new image has been uploaded i need this to happen

[image]

I can't even begin to get a grip of how i could make this.

Should i make the ajax return the  files?
How can i make the sliding work fully with new updates? at the moment i have it working with one image which is hidden and then has a position of left:-36px; so it is hidden ofscreen, then i change it to left:0px; and it slides across while moving the others, and this works great, but how could i make it so it can handle multiple imgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append you new image like that :

```
$("#slide").append('<img id="newimg"src="image.png"  />');
```

or use before() or after() for define the position of your new imagehttp://api.jquery.com/before/

with an overflow on #slide in your css.

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: use animate() in Jquery , really easy and work perfectly  [http://api.jquery.com/animate/](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Okay thank you, is there a way i can use the data that has been retrieved from a ajax post in a append?

Comment: when you do that :  `$.ajax({    
        type : "post",
        url : 'you-php files',
        success: function(fool) {}});` fool contain the data  from the ajax post . So you can use that in your append after .